# Cycles to external renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a model in Cycles, I am trying to use Mitsuba Renderer and just about everything goes wrong so far. I can give more precise problems I get, but there are just so many of them. Does it work out-of-the-box for you or is there some typical pipeline I should follow? Or do you just create all materials and things in the another renderer and never use the conversion?

I also tried LuxRenderer, but it says it couldn't load pylux and pyluxcore. It still works somehow, but "Convert Cycles Scene" also spits out a load of warning and errors. So it doesn't look like it is doing to work unless I redefine just about everything in my scene.

Comment: I use luxrender sometimes, make sure you install it correctly and it will work ok.

Comment: @Supahfly, I installed a dev build now and it imports pylux and pycore. However, I get black background instead of enviroment, no bump mapping, no light (even though I have a sun lamp), a crash exporting the material (ERROR: Export aborted: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bl_idname') and loads of Warnings like WARNING: Unsupported node type LIGHT_PATH, RBG, MATH, MIX_RGB and BRIGHTCONTRAST. Is this situation normal? Do you them spend time tuning all of this in Lux, creating new materials, adding new lamps, etc or does it just work?

Comment: For clarification im using luxrender 1.6.0 build 16132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no further answers: no, this doesn't work out of the box. Converter misses many nodes and some Nodes like "Light Path" are not possible to keep, if you want to use bidirectional path tracing. Node editor in Lux shows a warning sign near the nodes which were not correctly converted. To keep track of the conversion, one should run Blender in Terminal, as errors and warnings will be printed there.

Apart from that, many things can go wrong. The textures packed in .blend won't be loaded, multiple render layers are likely to be a problem.

Comment: It would be great if you could report your issues in the [LuxRender forum](http://www.luxrender.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=16) so we can fix them. Some of them sound like bugs, packed textures should work for example.

The warning sign in the node editor is not related to Cycles scene conversion, but to the Lux API you are using. The converter creates nodetrees for the new LuxCore API, and they are not always compatible with the old Classic API.
See more about this [here](http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxBlend25_LuxCore_NodeEditor).